# Does explicit conversion modify the object?

Tags: c#, asp.net, string, server-variables, explicit-conversion

Does explicit conversion like `(string)object` will modify the object itself?
When I am coding in visual C# in ASP.NET, I met a strange thing:

I type:

```
NameValueCollection coll;
coll = Request.ServerVariables;
LoginStatue1.Text += coll.GetValues("REMOTE_USER")[0] + "." + (string)coll["REMOTE_USER"] + "." + coll.GetValues("REMOTE_USER")[0];
```

The result is

> ..username

That means the first `coll.GetValues("REMOTE_USER")[0]` doesn't get anything while after `(string)coll["REMOTE_USER"]`, the second `coll.GetValues("REMOTE_USER")[0]` get the username.

So does explicit conversion change the object itself?

Comment: It depend on the explicit operator used...

Comment: How to explain this?..

Comment: Explicit conversion operators are generally immutable but could have potential side effects when working with mutable reference types. Your question doesn't provide enough detail to be able to say for sure what's going on.

Comment: You can define custom explicit operator (explicit cast) that return new instance of object. `public static explicit operator string(object i)
{
 return "Object is: "+ i.ToString();
}`

Comment: @M.Babcock thank you, but for I just met this problem, after the `(string)`, the result becomes different, so I think `(string)` must modify the `coll`.

Comment: @Zirkonix thank you, for `(string)`, does it change it?

Comment: The explicit cast is not effecting the underlying object, in fact it has no effect in this case as the result from the `NameValueCollection` indexer property is already a `string` type.

Comment: Cast to object to string should be immutable but I can't be sure for this specific exemple since we don't have enough information to be sure whats really going on.

Comment: If possible you need to step into the code with a debugger. The coll.GetValues() is returning something, which means the `NameValueCollection` contains the key you are asking for, otherwise you'd get an exception from the `[0]` index. Is the code above exactly the code that you are using?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, of course, explicit conversion changes the object.
First of all you won't be able to cast objects to string, C# doesn't allow it.

If you are able to cast, the object will behave like the current datatype, for e.g.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int i = 0;
        char j = (char)i;
        j--;
        Console.WriteLine(j);
    }
}
```

Output: ?
Note that the output is not -1, because the behaviour changed.

Comment: Most native explicit conversion functions are immutable and will create a _new_ reference to hold the value rather than changing the value in place so the first line of your answer is incorrect.

Comment: So that means most conversion will make a place for duplicate then convert it, and then assign it to target variable right?

Answer (score 0):

To make things clearer, I would suggest to try something like this:

```
LoginStatue1.Text =  string.Format("1st=({0}),2nd=({1}),3rd=({2})", 
coll.GetValues("REMOTE_USER")[0],  
(string) coll["REMOTE_USER"], 
coll.GetValues("REMOTE_USER")[0]);
```

What do you get as the result ? I'd expect the 1st and 3rd items to be the same.

e.g. if I run this self contained example:

```
        NameValueCollection  coll;
        coll = new NameValueCollection();
        coll.Add("REMOTE_USER", "Tom");
        coll.Add("REMOTE_USER", "Dick");
        coll.Add("REMOTE_USER", "Harry");
        LoginStatue1.Text =  string.Format("1st=({0}),2nd=({1}),3rd=({2})", coll.GetValues("REMOTE_USER")[0],  (string) coll["REMOTE_USER"], coll.GetValues("REMOTE_USER")[0]);
```

I get :  1st=(Tom),2nd=(Tom,Dick,Harry),3rd=(Tom)